# Is case after case in a switch efficient?

Tags: language-agnostic, efficiency, switch-statement

Just a random question regarding switch case efficiency in case after case; is the following code (assume pseudo code):

```
function bool isValid(String myString){
   switch(myString){
   case "stringA":
   case "stringB":
   case "stringC":
      return true;
   default:
      return false;
}
```

more efficient than this:

```
function bool isValid(String myString){
   switch(myString){
   case "stringA":
      return true;
   case "stringB":
      return true;
   case "stringC":
      return true;
   default:
      return false;
}
```

Or is the performance equal? I'm not thinking in a specific language but if needed let's assume it's Java or C (for this case would be needed to use chars instead of strings).

Comment: it will depend from compiler to compiler. However, efficient way (first block on top) is a win-win in maintainability.

Comment: It depends on the compiler, did you try profiling for both methods?

Comment: Nop I have not tried profiling, but that's a good idea, I will check in netbeans.

Comment: Are the strings constants?  How about using a HashSet?

Comment: Tried the profiling in the netbeans java ide but the results show that there isn't much difference between each method (in milliseconds), at least with 1000000 calls to each function and with 9 cases in switch. :) Jon Strayer, hashset/hashmap here isn't really needed I believe since it's just 9 cases of strings, and the function will be only called every 5 seconds in the real application. I was just curious if there were any real difference between the two methods.

Comment: I want to apologize for the presumptuousness of my edit comment.

Comment: By the way, there is one catch - at least in C, string comparisons can be done in `if` statements but cann't be done in `switch` statement.

Comment: @Dipan Mehta I know that, I also mentioned it in the bottom: "C (for this case would be needed to use chars instead of strings)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It quite depends on compiler. However, as a simple rule, switch is uses JUMP statement (equivalent to GO TO statement) to start from desired point on match condition. So in this case, if multiple condition jumps to same segment or code or different it doesn't add additional conditional check overhead.

One more comparison :

the code `if(arg == CASE_1 || arg == CASE_2 || arg == CASE_3)` will actually add conditional check with arg == CASE_1 as well as arg == CASE_2 even if arg is actually CASE_3. On the other hand, switch will result in only 1 comparison operation in either way.

In both the above case, i think number of CPU cycles will be identical - because they will amount to 1 condition check and one pop instruction. However, the later will take 2 more redundant instruction in memory. So it is slightly inefficient from code size point of view.

Comment: If I understood correctly the first method only does one condition check even if `myString=="stringA"` right? `case "stringB": case "stringC":` are automatically jumped, or are they checked too (in the stringA case)? //Edit: did a quick test in java debugger and seems its does the jump with only one check in stringA case.

Comment: @RandomGuy extended my answer. Basically if multiple condition having same routines to execute, doesn't add overhead in switch case at all.

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency shouldn't be your concern here.

**Code complexity and maintainability** should be your primary concern here.

You should question whether you're operating at the appropriate level of abstraction here.

Emphasis: Why do you feel the need to reach for this hammer (i.e. many `case` statements in a `switch` block)?

Recommendation: Take a look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126409/109941).

Comment: I'm using many cases because I need to check 10 strings and return true or false depending if the String being verified is in that "list" or not.

Comment: @RandomGuy: In that case, you should reexamine your algorithm. // How big is the list? If it's big, why don't you lean on an index in a database?

Comment: @RandomGuy: Based on your comment, I *strongly* advise you to submit your entire problem (or algorithm) to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Something just doesn't smell right.

Comment: It's not that big, it's 9 or 10 strings only. //Edit: Thanks for the advice. I will probably extend the list after but then I will rewrite this without the switch. But when I was writing this code, this efficiency question raised (since it can apply to other codes, even with less cases).

Comment: Not only does this fail to answer the question, it's a bit of a knee-jerk reaction to a switch. Would you have complained at `return mystring == "stringa" || mystring == "stringb"` etc. (Obviously better laid out than I can in a comment.)

Comment: @pdr: Nope, not at all; but he said 10 strings (not one or two).

Comment: @JimG. Increasing the number of strings doesn't increase complexity or reduce maintainability, as long as there remain essentially two conditions (valid or other) and this conditional statement, in whatever form it takes, is the only thing that method does.

Comment: @JimG. I'd like to point out that I didn't downvote this (yet), so your hunting for another question on which to retaliate looks especially bitter.

Comment: @pdr I'm wonder if your suggestion is more "fast" than with the switch? Isn't that equal to something like this (in terms of performance): `if(myString=="stringA") return true; if (myString=="stringB") return true; `.

Comment: @RandomGuy: Correct. I was not suggesting that for speed, or because I think it's in any way better. I was pointing out that people react harshly to any use of switch (usually because of a misinterpretation of Martin Fowler's comments in Refactoring) while ignoring very similar constructs.

Comment: @pdr Oh ok I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Layout of case labels is not the bottleneck in this code - string comparison is.

Typically for case labels the compiler is just going to generate a simple jump table and go to the appropriate line of code depending on the value being tested.  This is important knowledge - the code that you write in a high-level language often bears very little resemblance to the low-level representation of it that the compiler generates.  So you can't make a direct observation about potential performance just by looking at the high-level code.

In the case of C#/Java/whatever, languages which allow strings to appear as case label entries, the rules change.  Now the compiler can no longer generate a jump table, it has to do a lot of string comparisons to determine the appropriate branch to follow.  And strings are slow.

If you're worried about efficiency of this code, then consider using an enum instead.  If you can't (or won't), you can get extra performance out of it by putting the most commonly hit conditions at the top.  If this isn't a performance-critical part of your program then do nothing - it's already good enough.

Comment: Good answer. Yes Enums would be a good option if performance was critical or if I had many cases, another option would be use a hash table this if I had many strings I believe like how Jon Strayer mentioned. I was just wondering which one of the two blocks would be the fastest, we can assume it's chars or ints instead of strings for c/c++ for example.

Comment: a prefix trie will be able to create a table to jump which can be traversed in O(n) instead of the naive k O(n) comparisons